# can someone confirm my understanding about asp.net live cycle?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

my goal is to find a way to update the title of the page at the very last moment before it get created

I have a master page and a content place holder that always contain a page with a specific property.

that property can be updated anywhere in the code but I want the final value of that tag to be the html title

is the prerender event of that page the best place to set the title?

Comment: See the chart under Additional Page Life Cycle Considerations in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx. PreRender probably is the best place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PreRender` is *one* place where you could set the title, another -later- is `PreRenderComplete`:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.PreRenderComplete += Page_PreRenderComplete;
    this.SaveStateComplete += Page_SaveStateComplete;
}
```

**Edit**: Just noticed that you can even use `SaveStateComplete` event, that should be latest place where you could change the title:

```
protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Title = "late title";
}


protected void Page_SaveStateComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Title = "very late title";
}
```

[image]

Some additional informations about page-title in masterpages and Site Map Data:

[Dynamically Setting the Page's Title in ASP.NET 2.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20210422200927/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051006-1.aspx)