# Page.Title not acting as expected with master pages

Tags: .net, master-pages, page-title

According to a few sources ([including this one](http://kirtimdarji.blogspot.co.il/2011/07/page-life-cycle-of-master-page-with.html)) when using a master page the page's `Load` happens before the master page's `Load`.

When I assign `Page.Title` a value in the page's `Load` it works.

If I write `Page.Title += "J"` in the master page's `Load` the title becomes `J`, regardless if a value was previously assigned.

In all cases, when I `Response.Write(Page.Title)` later on in the master page's `Load` it's empty.

What am I missing out here?

**EDIT** (some code):

default.aspx

```
Page.Title = "Title";
```

Master page

```
Page.Title += " - More title";
.
.
.
Response.Write("TITLE: " + Page.Title);
```

I get `TITLE:` in the window and `- More title` in the browser header.

**EDIT** (some debugging):

I added the following to my aspx and to the master page:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("<!--DEBUG-" + (debug_counter++) + "- TITLE: " + Page.Title + "-->\r\n");
}
protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("<!--DEBUG-" + (debug_counter++) + "- TITLE: " + Page.Title + "-->\r\n");
}
protected void Page_Render(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("<!--DEBUG-" + (debug_counter++) + "- TITLE: " + Page.Title + "-->\r\n");
}
protected void Page_SaveStateComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("<!--DEBUG-" + (debug_counter++) + "- TITLE: " + Page.Title + "-->\r\n");
}
```

Plus a few similar lines throughout the `Load` function of both. They all come out blank.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, thank you! Would using different parts of the life cycle make a difference? It shouldn't, really.

Comment: Show some code that's producing a result you don't expect.  `Page.Title += "J"` in the master page's Load event will append "J" to whatever title was previously defined.

Comment: @Joe, that's the problem, it doesn't.

Comment: what does your markup look like?  Is the `<head>` element in the Master or Content page?

Comment: @Joe, Master page has `<head runat="server"><title></title></head>`. I tried to remove the `title` element - it made no difference.

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger and inspect Page.Title at each relevant point.

Comment: @Joe, it's blank all through (see latest edit). Even right after I set a value (which the browser does use later on).

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger.  Break on each line that sets Page.Title.  Inspect its value.  Keep stepping through the code one line at a time and inspecting Page.Title.

Comment: @Joe, blank all through my code. But at the end the browser does display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `Page.Header.Title` instead. It works.

From [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210422200927/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051006-1.aspx) I understood they're supposed to be the same. Apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

Master pages [behave like child controls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10525258/284240) on a page: the master page Init event occurs before the page Init and Load events, and **the master page Load event occurs after the page Init and Load events**.

I've answered recently the question what's the best place to set a page's title from the MasterPage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10525258/284240

> you can even use SaveStateComplete event, that should be latest place where you could change the title:

```
protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Title = "late title";
} 

protected void Page_SaveStateComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Title = "very late title";
}
```

Comment: All this didn't make a difference. See latest edit to question.